# Access menu class from MainActivity class in android

Tags: android, menu, android-activity

I have two different classes. My main activity class and a separate menu.class. I want to be able to get the menu class to load from the mainactivity.class. The menu button does not work on my device or emulator when the mainActivity class is running. I am not sure how to call the menu.class from the mainActivity. I do not want to put the menu java code in the mainActivity.

I am asking for the way to add a snip of code to load a menu activity from one class to another, not to fix my code. I can not find any examples online to show how to load a menu class that is not also written in your main activity class.

```
public class lifeMenu extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.life_menu);
}
```

That is a snip of my menu activity. My main activity is called MainActivity

Comment: I am asking for the way to add a snip of code to load a menu activity from one class to another, not to fix my code. I can not find any examples online to show how to load a menu class that is not also written in your main activity class

Answer (score 0):

You can make your MainActivity extend your MenuActvity that entends Activity. Hard to know since you did not provide a snip of your menu class.